# JS Regex - string can start/end with a period but it should not contain multiple periods in a row

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm validating the string and it can contain any character, it can start/end with a period but it should not contain multiple periods in a row. How would I achieve that?

Valid string:

- `{.tr.i._g`

Not valid string:

- `{.tr..i._g`
- `.tr...i.g`

This is what I've got so far:

`^.*[^\.\.]*.$`

Comment: Hello again, Dot boy. Are you sure you can't just perform negative validation with that one? I mean to check if `..` is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this regex with a negative loikahead:

```
/^(?!.*\.\.).+/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AmmDyg/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!.*\.\.)`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if 2 dots are foudn anywhere
- `.+`: Match 1+ of any characcter

Comment: And if the string were `"abc\n..d"`, i.e. with a newline in it anywhere before the two periods?

Comment: Then just replace `.` with `[^]`. You should better ask OP if this is requirement. It appears from question that there is no `\n` in a row.

Comment: The OP said "I'm validating the string and it can contain any character ...". I don't go by two or three examples because "any character" would require an infinity of examples if you only go by the examples.

Comment: Why should I ask? My answer will work whether it's a requirement or not. It's your answer that is now in question.

Comment: I did not copy your answer. There aren't too many ways of doing this. And the point was that I think your answer is wrong because of the newline issue. And I presented an alternative to `s` mode.

Comment: As I already commented above, there is an obvious `/^(?![^]*\.\.)[^]+$/` solution and there is a different working regex posted by @Edward as well.

Answer (score 0):

This `/^[^.]*(?:\.(?!\.)[^.]*)*$/`

Comment: What if the input were `"ab.c..d"`? You can't use `[^.]*` because there might be an intervening period before you get to the two consecutive periods.

Comment: `[^.]` means no dot. Only dot allowed is checked for no adjacent (forward) dot.

Answer (score -1):

If it must contain at least one character, then:

```
/^(?!.*?\.\.).+$/s

^             # Matches start of string
(?!.*?\.\.)   # Negative lookahead assertion that the input does not contain two successive periods
.+            # Matches one or more characters
$             # Matches the end of the string
```

The `s` flag is required else `.` will not match a newline character. So if the string were, "abc\n..d", the `s` flag would be required to find the two successive periods.

If you do not want to use the `s` flag, then use instead of `.`, `[\s\S]`, which will match any character:

```
/^(?![\s\S]*?\.\.)[\s\S]+$/
```